# Unable to download CodeDeploy agent from Windows Server with IAM Role attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to download codedeploy following AWS docs:

[Install the CodeDeploy agent for Windows Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-windows.html)

To do it, i need to run following command which basically downloads the file on temporary folder for my region us-east-1:

```
powershell.exe -Command Read-S3Object -BucketName aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 -Key latest/codedeploy-agent.msi -File c:\temp\codedeploy-agent.msi
```

On that instance I attached an IAM Role which has AmazonS3FullAccess policy. I'm getting this error when I execute the command:

```
Read-S3Object : No credentials specified or obtained from persisted/shell defaults.
```

I'm aware I could fix this adding personal credentials but since this is not considered a good practice I would like to download the client without tackling it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has a similar problem.

This was caused because I previously migrated a custom windows AMI to a different AWS region.

The instance profile metadata server was pointing to old region server. You need to change that to point to the new region:

```
Import-Module (Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Ec2Launch.psd1')
Add-Routes
```